# what is 'SingleBlockManager' in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I get an error message when I am using some library

```
AttributeError: 'SingleBlockManager' object has no attribute 'to_dense'
```

to_dense is a method for dataframe, therefore I assume SingleBlockManager should be a dataframe in my case. Does anyone know what SingleBlockManager is in Pandas so that I can possibly guess where my error is? Here is the last bit of the error message.

```
/users/xx/xxxx/pyenvs/xx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.16.2+xxx1-   
py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/sparse/series.py in get_values(self)
    228     def get_values(self):
    229         """ same as values """
--> 230         return self._data._values.to_dense().view()
    231
    232     @property
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SingleBlockManager` is an internal data structure which (essentially) holds the pieces of a `Series` - the index and values.  You'd need to post some more context to see what's actually triggering the error.

```
In [1]: s = pd.Series([1,2,3])

In [2]: s._data
Out[2]:
SingleBlockManager
Items: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
IntBlock: 3 dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, so if SingleBlockManager holds the content of a dateframe, it will have the to_dense() method, otherwise not?

Comment: No - it never has that method - in your traceback above, it's being called on `._values` of the `SingleBlockManager`.  Try to reduce your problem to a reproducible example.